# Numbered String to Int with leading zeros

Tags: string, go, integer

For a numbered string (`1234`) I normally use the package `strconv` with the function `Atoi` to convert from string to int in Go. However, what is the idiomatic way of approaching this if the numbered string starts with leading zeros (e.g. `01234`)?

Slicing the string and then converting the `[]string` to `[]int`, is one approach, but is it the best/idiomatic way Go-ing about it?

**Update 1:**
From input string `01234`, expected output `01234` as any type int (in any kind of simple or composed type of int, e.g. `foo := "01234"` to `bar = []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`).

Is there an idiomatic (or standard package func) to approach this problem, or is the string to rune/byte conversation (do some business logic and then convert back) necessary when the variable has one or more leading zeros (e.g. `01234` or `00001`).

**Update 2:** Just to make it completely clear, as I can feel the question can be clarified future: `foo, _ := strconv.Atoi("01234")` returns `1234` as an `int` (and same result can be obtained in other ways with `strings` package etc.).

The question here is, how (if possible, in Go idiomatic) can I get the result **with** the leading zeros, that is, `01234` (and NOT `1234`) in type `int`?

Comment: What is your expected output - 1234? Or do you want to treat this number in 8-base?

Comment: you can use `strconv.Atoi` with leading zeros as far as I can tell: https://go.dev/play/p/ZdQI7LGiipf

Answer (score 2):

use `strings.TrimLeft(s, "0")` to remove leading zeroes from the string.

Comment: No. He wants to keep zero ahead

Answer (score 2):

```golang
fmt.Printf("%01d ", 5) // 5
fmt.Printf("%02d ", 5) // 05
fmt.Printf("%03d ", 5) // 005
fmt.Printf("%04d ", 5) // 0005

myInt := fmt.Sprintf("%05d ", 5)
fmt.Println(myInt)     // 00005
```

https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#pkg-overview

Comment: Interesting solution - you got me almost all happy there, but `myInt` is type `string` and not `int`. After thinking about the problem I don't think there is any straight forward solution that won't require a string conversation to rune/byte, do some business logic and then convert back to string. It's actually a bit strange thinking about it - this case (i.e. dropping of leading zeros for any given `int`) that has this inherent problem and needs a but of conversion to do the trick.

Comment: when you do some logic whit them you don't need them with zero heed. and when you render them you don`t need it as a int type.

Comment: Well, that depends. If you do something like counting digits for validation and you depend on the string being a fix length, and you *only* want to work with type `int`, you're back to do some flow control handling on the type due to one or more dropped leading zeros. This, of course, won't happen with a string to byte/rune conversion, but only with the string to int conversion with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string of decimals to a slice of integers for those decimal values, loop over the string and convert the rune to the corresponding integer using subtraction:

```
func toIntSlice(s string) ([]int, error) {
    var result []int
    for _, r := range s {
        if r < '0' || r > '9' {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("not an integer %s", s)
        }
        result = append(result, int(r-'0'))
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

Example use:

```
foo := "01234" 
bar, _ := toIntSlice(foo)
// bar is []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/etHtApYoWUi